# ZIP folder whitou root

Tags: php, zip, directory

I have a script that is invoked when to compress the contents of the folder "output", but
when I try to load the contents of the folder "Outpup" located in the folder www / projectname, I compress the file in the root directory C:\

myscript

```
$rootpath="./Output";
$destinazione="./Output/lista.zip";
 Zip($rootpath,$destinazione);
```

function ZIP

```
function Zip($source, $destination)

{

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

I need to compress only the contents of the folder "output", but in the zip I get the following nested folders

```
c:\
└─ Program Files (x86)
 └─  www
  └─ Separalista
   └─output
     ├─ folder1
     │ └─ file.csv
     └─ folder2 
       └─ file.csv
```

I would like to find inside the zip file only subfolders "output"

```
output
  ├─ folder1
  │  └─ file.csv
  └─ folder2 
     └─ file.csv
```

thanks to all

Comment: Try having the destination as a folder other than the source. If they're the same, as you have it, problems can arise.

Comment: I tried to change destination but is always the same problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is - your working directory, represented by dot in your `$rootpath`, can be anything, nothing makes it script's own directory. To change working directory to script's one, use:

```
chdir( dirname ( realpath ( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

or, in PHP 5.3.0 or later, simply

```
chdir( __DIR__ );
```

at the beginning of your script.

If that does not work, you must make some bit deeper changes. Attach paths to your script directly to the variable containing directories, like this:

```
$rootpath = __DIR__ . '/Output';
$destinazione = $rootpath . '/lista.zip';
```

Above should work, assuming your file is in project's root directory. If not, modify `$rootpath` accordingly. In PHP pre 5.3.0 use `dirname ( realpath ( __FILE__ ) )` in place of `__DIR__`.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand where to apply your suggestion

Comment: @MarcoAttanasio as the first line of your script, for example.